# Can Stack Exchange include the number of edits a user has made on a site in /users/<id>/edits?

Tags: feature-request, api-v2.1, editing

Originally, I wrote:

> In the old review queue, users could see their progress towards the Copy Editor and Strunk and White badges, but since the new review queues were implemented, this information is no longer available.

But it seems Mat has pointed out that the information is still available in the review Suggested Edit queue by hovering over the progress indicator. Still, adding this to the API may be beneficial.

Is it possible to add this information to the Stack Exchange API so power users and developers can obtain this information?  I picture that being added to the API as `/users/<id>/edits`.

I believe the revisions tab includes tag edits, which don't count towards things like the Strunk and White and Copy Editor badges. So that has proven insufficient and is why I propose this information be made available under `/edits` and not `/revisions`.

Comment: The information is visible in the review queues, in the popup that show badge progress (hover over the thingy that tells you how many reviews you did in that queue).

Comment: Thanks @Mat, that information is sort of hard to find. That makes this feature request slightly less important to me, but it still may be good to add to the API.

Comment: Sure, wasn't saying it shouldn't be implemented. The revisions tab also tracks edits to your own posts (which don't count), and multiple edits to the same post, which are counted only once for the badges. So it's not easy to extract the badge progress from that.

Comment: @Mat - The revisions tab includes tag edits, which don't count toward the badge. I did go through once and count every edit myself. That was a pain. But knowing that info is still in review does help. Thanks again!